# How to call method with block in Object C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have declared method as:

```
- (void) authorizeUser:(OauthObject *) user withUsername: (NSString *) username withPassword: (NSString *) password completionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)) CallCompletion;
```

I try to call this method like as:

```
[[ManagerServerRequest sharedManagerServerRequest] authorizeUser:(OauthObject *) withUsername:self.login.text withPassword:self.login.text completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        // TODO
    }]
```

Where `ManagerServerRequest sharedManagerServerRequest` is singlton object.

I get error:
`use undeclared  identifier WithUsername`

How to call this method correctly?

Review:
I pass `oauthObj`:

```
OauthObject* oauthObj = [[OauthObject alloc] init];

[[ManagerServerRequest sharedManagerServerRequest]
 authorizeUser: oauthObj and:
 withUsername:self.login.text
 withPassword:self.login.text
 completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
     // TODO
 }]
```

I can error

Comment: That error message doesn't match the code.

Comment: `authorizeUser:(OauthObject *)` you kinda should have an object there...

Comment: What do you mean? I actually send object OauthObject

Comment: Either you didn't post the actual code from Xcode, or you're *really*, *really* confused on how to call methods in Objective-C.

Comment: The code you posted can't possibly compile. Post your actual code. If that **IS** your actual code, you are in over your head (as @Avi says).

Comment: @Bababa can you post method documentation / comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is unrelated to block syntax. In your code

```
[[ManagerServerRequest sharedManagerServerRequest] 
    authorizeUser:(OauthObject *) 
    withUsername:self.login.text 
    withPassword:self.login.text 
    completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        // TODO
}]
```

You are missing the actual argument for `authorizeUser:`, replace `(OauthObject *)` with the actual object and you are fine.

Comment: OP, remove the extranous `and:` from your update's code. Where did that come from anyway?

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't compile, but that's what you said in your question anyway :-)

From the error message, it looks like you are using WithUsername when you should be using withUsername.

Comment: OP did in fact not copy-paste the error but made a few typos when transcribing. Apart from the not correct transcription, the problem (and solution) I decribed in my answer is the relevant part.